# Using Google maps api inside div not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I've been trying to add google maps to my page with no avail. My code works fine independently but when I add to a real webpage the map doesn't show at all.

```
 <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

And the page looks like this 
[image]

As you can see, the div pops up but not the map. How would I get this to show?

Comment: Check your console log if it throws any error..

Comment: Nope, no errors

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/3xquh1gs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `myMap` function has never been called. You can call it like,

```
function myMap() {
   ... 
}

myMap();
```

or use callback parameter on the script..

```
<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=myMap"> </script>
```

**Edit**

You're calling it wrong, it should be an `&`, not `&amp;` in your script parameter. Try to change your code to,

```
<div id="map" style="width:500px;height:500px"></div>

<script>
    function myMap() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
            zoom: 5
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    }
</script>

<script async defer src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&callback=myMap"> </script>
```

For more detail, check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dzc8d9oo/).

**- Edit 2 -**

I have no idea why you can't get it to work in your site. Since I could do it just fine.

[image: Google map on memphis.edu]

Below are the script that I inject during runtime on the console in your site.

```
$('.content--body__wrapper').append('<div id="map" />')
$('#map').attr('style', 'width:500px; height:500px')
$('.content--body__wrapper').append(`<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>`);
$('.content--body__wrapper').append(`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI&callback=initMap" async defer></script>`);
```

What I can tell from your screenshot is your `initMap` function does not get called. And I am not sure if it's the callback from google map since it provides no error in your console.

Below is an alternative approach,  that you might want to try. Try to call `initMap` on the js instead of callback.

```
<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBcwtM8EBe7BE1NyPbU5SDYVYoBBtbtpTI"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var map;
        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                zoom: 8
            });
        }
        initMap();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I added callback to script and calling my map function but it's still not showing.

Comment: @JCole Can you try to add `async defer` to the script? It might have loaded first from your browser cache before the rest of your page and failing the call.. Or just use the first approach..

Comment: I've edited my code above to reflect my new code but it's still showing blank...does it have something to do with my div?

Comment: @JCole Nope, it has nothing to do with your div.. its just a container that should contain a full width and height of google map.. judging from the size, it should have google map inside it. Check my edited answer..

Comment: @JCole No you don't have to.. It's just a sheer habit of mine to start a fiddle. Wait.. I have no jquery in my fiddle too..

Comment: I asked because the map still isn't showing in a browser and I also tried looking at the jsfiddle source for the code and I looked at a lot of examples but it seems most people were using jquery and that's why it didn't work. The jsfiddle and the code works but whenever I add it to a browser in either way it still shows blank

Comment: @JCole Are you aware that in your script, you had `&amp;callback=myMap`? Well it should be `&callback=myMap`.

Comment: Yea I took out the amp; that was unnecessary and changed the code and picture above to reflect but still nothing...am i missing something that I should instantiate in the head?

Comment: @JCole Can you post your final code again? I don't think you're missing anything. But you can should always check your console log for anything..

Comment: Ok I edited my above code again and no I'm not getting any errors or warnings on the console. I'm also assuming wit this code I don't have to add anything to the head of the code

Comment: Thanks a lot choz!  Using the script  that you inserted on runtime into the console I was able to get the map to finally show. Seems like using jquery is a much easier option and it's to much code. Now that I can make a basic map I can go on to customizing it more so are there and sites that you could recommend where I can learn jquery since I know next to almost nothing about it.